# Loading animation for `top x% this year` appears on top of `next badge`

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

This happened one time, although I haven't been able to reproduce it.

I opened the profiles page, and instead of instantly seeing the `Top x% this year`, I saw loading 3-dot animation, which appears on top of text down below `Next Badge`[image]

Comment: But did it load? It might've been a network hiccup, and if you can't reproduce it, I don't really see the point in reporting it...

Comment: I am not sure when does the percentage label require loading animation. But when it does show the animation, it shows it on top of the text below, instead of, perhaps showing it in the same place as the percentage text. :)